# JavaScript, get value of table without ID

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

This is my table and I want to get the value of "Spielzeit" and "Coins".

I've tried a lot like

```
document.querySelector("div.page Spielzeit");

document.getElementById('page').getElementsByTagName('th');

document.querySelectorAll("#page th");
```

But nothing worked.

I cant find my table, because there is no table id.

Maybe you know how to "find" my values.

Thanks

```
<div id="page">
    <table style="margin-left: 125px; margin-top:50px; width: 300px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Benutzername:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">Dantes999</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Reich:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">Not empire</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Charaktere:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">0</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Spielzeit:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;"> Minuten</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Coins:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">0 I-Coins</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Coins:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">0 V-Coins</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Lagerpasswort:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">000000</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Loeschcode:</th>
                <th style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">1234567</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just add an ID to your table?

Comment: What value are you trying to find? Minuten ???

Comment: The first selector of course “doesn’t work”, because there is no element with the tag name `Spielzeit`. The other two should return elements ... but you’d have to do some additional filtering on those afterwards to find the relevant elements.

Comment: If you can use XPath: `//th[text()='Spielzeit:']/following-sibling::th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one table on your page, `document.querySelector("table").get(0)` should give you your table.

Second, `page` is an id in your HTML, not a class. So it should be selected with `#` not `.`

You can change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="page">

<table style="margin-left: 125px; margin-top:50px; width: 300px;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Benutzername:</th> <th class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">Dantes999</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Reich:</th> <th 
class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">Not empire</th>
    </tr><tr>
    </tr><tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Charaktere:</th> 
<th class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Spielzeit:</th> <th 
  class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;"> Minuten</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Coins:</th> <th 
 class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">0 I-Coins</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Coins:</th> <th 
 class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">0 V-Coins</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Lagerpasswort:</th> <th class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">000000</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="item" style="text-align: left;">Loeschcode:</th> <th class="value" style="color: #9e7538; text-align: right;">1234567</th>
    </tr>

    </tbody></table>
```

Now you can use `document.querySelector(".item[text='Spielzeit']);` to select the corresponding item and get the text of it's next element for the value

So your code should be:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".item[text='Spielzeit']");
var value = elem.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.value').html;
```

Comment: I cant change the table..

I just want to get some elements...
On Phyton ive done like


find_between(content, "<th>Coins:</th>", "<br/>"):
        start = s.index(first) + len(first)
        end = s.index(last, start)
        return s[start:end]